# Delaware : Legal Notice by email

Tags: contract-law, delaware

My contract (Delaware Law) doesn't specify how notices have to be delivered.

By default, is email a legal notice ?

I want to terminate a contract and have to notify the person of the termination.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to check with a local attorney familiar with the local court's rules and the customs of the jurisdiction. But if you have the person's physical address, why not just use it and send it registered mail? Sort of takes the entire uncertainty part out of the ordeal. I don't know if notice requirements will be more or less stringent in your jurisdiction, but, for example, service of process by electronic means, such as Facebook, is just starting to enter the realm of possibility (what I mean by that is court rulings recognizing them as valid are relatively new and the issue has not been fully litigated yet).

So, while there is a possibility your notice of termination of a contract by email would be sufficient, it would be best to check with a local attorney to understand the legal requirements in your situation and in your jurisdiction.

Comment: I like sharing knowledge, that's what stackexchange and Wikipedia stands for.
I ask it here in hope that we can get an actual answer and that it might help all the startups with same problems in the future.

Comment: Despite the nice thought, this is unfortunately impossible due to variations in the law between jurisdictions and the fact that, as I indicated above, providing notice for any purpose via online media is a relatively new phenomenon and has not seen full treatment by the courts yet, so any answer you receive anywhere will be less than complete. Also, from the sidebar: "Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner."